# K2 item association

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2

I want to associate the k2 items in my website. I have been reading around on articles and forum saying that is possible and some others the opposite.
So is there a way to associate my k2 items in the front end, just like joomla articles?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "associate"?

Comment: Hello JeffT, thank you for your reply.

I mean language association. when i'm on a specifik k2 item and if i switch languages, i won't be redirected to the homepage but in the same item, only in the other language.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, K2 in its current version does not support Item Associations, similar to what you get in Joomla's core articles, when you enable the feature in the language filter plugin.

One possible workaround to create associations among the k2 items is by creating menu items for those k2 that you want to be associated. You will actually associate the menu items. This could work for a certain number of k2 items, it won't be an option if you have hundreds of them.

Otherwise, a 3rd party translation extension like [falang](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/falang) could be the solution.